# Linking an HTML form to a PHP file or just save it as a PHP file?

Tags: php, html

When creating a simple form which a PHP script will process, does it matter if we link to that form via the form tag? For example, we have:

```
<form name="studentapp" method="post">
```

With the PHP script being below the HTML form. The file is saved as a PHP itself, so it can interpret the PHP code. There isn't really anything special about the name. But how about this:

```
<form action="application.php" method="post">
```

Where the file is an HTML file, but it links to a PHP file for processing the data.

Is one better to use than the other?

EDIT: There is an error in the code I posted. One should use the action tag to link a separate PHP file for processing. (Thanks user Stony)

Comment: Do you mean `action="application.php"`?

Comment: a form can submit to any url it wants to. it doesn't care. You could have a form on your site that has `action="http://google.com"` and your browser would happily submit your form to google.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean action="application.php". I didn't realize this mistake until someone pointed it out to me down below. @Marc B so I suppose it doesn't matter if I do the PHP code in the same file or just link to the PHP file?

Comment: that's purely a preference and depending on what (if any) framework you're using.

Comment: What actually you are trying to do? If you want that data from an html from should be processed via PHP, you should put the PHP file name/path under 'action' attribute i.e. 'action=application.php'

Comment: Ah, I'm not using any framework. Just creating an online form to integrate into a website. In that case I think it wouldn't really matter whether I did the PHP code in just one file along with the HTML or if I did the HTML and linked the PHP to it.


@WisdmLabs I'm trying to process data submitted through a form using PHP. My inquiry was as to whether I should process the information in the same file (making the whole HTML/PHP file just a PHP file) or putting the file name/path under the action attribute, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them is wrong ;)

The `action` tag is to define the page to send the form to. The name is only an optional name to process the form via javascript for example.

```
<form name="myformname" action="application.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Is it a better practice to simply name the form and do the PHP code below the HTML? Or is it better to just use the action tag to link to the PHP file to process code?

Comment: @skeletonne it depends on situation.

Answer (score 0):

Besides of what's been said (that you need to use the action attribute) it depends on your workflow. If you want to display the form again, them it makes sense to keep everything on the same page. Or you can move your php processing block to the top of the page and exit if form has been submitted, therefore not showing the form again. I really don't think it matters if you use the same page or a different one. Again, it depends on your workflow.

Comment: I would like to do this all on one page. I'm not sure if I'd like the form to disappear after submission. I think it would help to prevent duplicate submissions, which is something that I need to fix. I'm only working on a localhost server right now (WAMP) so it is difficult to use the POST/REDIRECT/GET method when there are no other pages to redirect to.

Comment: How do you think leaving the form on the page prevents duplicate submission? You should always check if data got submitted and show a message to the user stating submission was successful.

Comment: I was saying that making the form disappear may help to prevent duplicate submission. Of course they can always refresh or go back, but they wouldn't hit the submit button more than once.

Comment: Yes. That's usually how I do the processing. On the top of the page my php code checks if there's a submission. If yes, process then or redirect or provide a link to somewhere else.

Comment: Cool, thank you for the information. I'll put my PHP code first.